# to_csv でファイル名を指定してもエラー FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python3, pandas

データフレームをcsvに出力したいのですが、to_csvが機能しません。
resultというデータフレームを以下のコードで出力しようとしても、エラーが出てしまいます。

**コード:**

```
result.to_csv('ディレクトリ名/ファイル名.csv',encoding='shift-jis')
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ディレクトリ名/ファイル名.csv'
```

なお、同じディレクトリのcsvを `pd.read_csv` コマンドで読み込むことはできますし、 `to_csv` のディレクトリ名を `"./"` のようにしてみてもやはり出力ができません。
なぜあるはずのフォルダに出力ができないようなことになっているのでしょうか？

Comment: ちなみに、`C:\Users\(Name)`フォルダには`to_csv`で書き込みできましたが、その下の`C:\Users\(Name)\Documents`フォルダにはなぜか同様のエラーで書き込みができません。。訳が分かりません。先日Windowsのリフレッシュをしたので、それが影響している可能性はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 質問はあとからでも編集できますので、ご検討ください。 / 過去の質問についても、回答が付いたまま放置しているものがあるようですが、解決しているものについては承認をお願いします。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: この記事 [デフォルトではオフ？ Windowsの｢ランサムウェアの防止｣機能は使うべき](https://www.lifehacker.jp/2019/08/why-you-should-use-windows-defenders-ransomware-prevent.html) の「コントロールされたフォルダーアクセス」の機能がONになっていたのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1):

Pythonの仕様で、

```
result.to_csv('ディレクトリ名/ファイル名.csv',encoding='shift-jis')
```

ではなく

```
result.to_csv('ディレクトリ名\\ファイル名.csv',encoding='shift-jis')`
```

ですね。よくある間違いです。
[ここ](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1904/16/news013.html)のエスケープシーケンスというところに書かれているものが参考になると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただ、pathの全ての'/'を'\\'に変えてみたり、最後の'/'を'\\'に変えてみたりしましたが、やはり機能してくれません…。

Comment: File Not Found Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory「直訳（ファイルが見つかりませんエラー：[Errno 2]そのようなファイルまたはディレクトリはありません）」ですので、ファイルかディレクトリのパスが間違っているようにしか見えません。あとPythonで上の階層に上がる為には"./"ではなく"../"ですよ。